# Google glass (GDK): Share multiple pictures with Google+

Tags: bitmap, google-plus, google-glass, google-gdk

The glassware I'm developing using the GDK takes multiple pictures in a burst. Now I'd like to share them with Google+ the same way the native "take a picture" glassware does, once the picture is taken, with, " ok, glass " " share with... ".  I already know how to process the voice tag/immersion menu.  What I'm looking for is the best way to share the pictures with Google+.  A related request would be to have the photos Auto Awesome.

Update: I saw this question was downvoted. If I could understand the reason for the downvote I could reformulate the question or withdraw it altogether. Given native glassware has this feature, it seems reasonable to ask how to incorporate it into my glassware

Comment: Thanks @Kara for making the tags more appropriate

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with GDK as of the XE11 sneak peek. If this is something you'd like added to the SDK, file an enhancement request in the [official issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list).